# Razor view Bootstrap control width

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a screen, I have added all the controls and all of them were aligned to grid perfectly as I have used Bootstrap. But at the end I have a control for Notes and I want it to span across entire row but it still doesn't cross the first column... is there is anyway to solve this?

Here is my razor (Code only related to the Notes section)

```
            <div class="row top-space">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-lg-2", @placeholder = "Notes" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="input-group notes-area">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 10, @cols = 500 } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row top-space">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-inline">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" style="margin: auto" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is my output:
[image: output]

I tried using TextArea and also tried specifying the Cols attribute but none of them worked. Is it because I have already dividing the entire screen into 3 columns?

Comment: do you have a sample bootply you could use to show us?

Comment: What you have should work. Things to try: 1) Make sure that all your opening and closing tags match up as they should. It's possible that the div your notes textarea is in is being limited in width by a parent div with some `col-*` class. 2) Check your `notes-area` class and make sure it doesn't do anything silly like set a width, max-width, etc. 3) Check to make sure the width of a textarea is not being limited by anything else in your CSS.

Comment: Thank you Chris, you were right... after examining the loaded HTML styles in chrome dev tools, I could see somewhere I was setting max-width incorrectly. I just removed it and it worked!